# Nested temp table in SQL FUNCTION, like select from (select..)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a possibility to make something like select from select - nested results temp table instead of original table used in function, not procedure?

This is works perfectly:

```
SELECT ID, PAR1, PAR2 INTO tempTABLE 
FROM originalTABLE
WHERE ..CONDITIONS..

SELECT TOP 1 (tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2) AS FinalResult
FROM tempTable tbl1
INNER JOIN tempTable tbl2 on tbl2.PAR1 > tbl1.PAR1
INNER JOIN tempTable tbl3 on tbl3.PAR1 > tbl2.PAR1
ORDER BY tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2

DROP TABLE tempTable
```

But I can't use it in function because of INSERT statement, so I try like this:

```
SELECT (tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2) AS FinalResult 
FROM ((SELECT ID, PAR1, PAR2 FROM originalTABLE
WHERE ..CONDITIONS.) AS tempTable) tbl1
    INNER JOIN tempTable tbl2 on tbl2.PAR1 > tbl1.PAR1
    INNER JOIN tempTable tbl3 on tbl3.PAR1 > tbl2.PAR1
    ORDER BY tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2
```

But it failed.

Comment: CTEs tend to give much more readable results than subqueries in these cases: `WITH tempTable AS (SELECT ID, PAR1, ...) SELECT TOP(1) FROM temptable tbl1 INNER JOIN tempTable tbl2 ...` Note that whether CTE or subquery, the perf characteristics of this can be quite different from using a temp table, because the optimizer does not typically materialize intermediate results (and when it does, not in the same way as when you do it explicitly).

Comment: Thanks for answer. What you mean in your about differences between cte and temp table? It could give different results in table?

Comment: No, the results will be identical, but the resulting query may perform differently. The optimizer will typically evaluate a subquery that's aliased multiple times separately each time.

Comment: For this reason CTE can be slower?

Comment: Yes, and it can also be faster. Hence "differently".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly replace your temporal table with a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
with tempTable as (
  SELECT ID, PAR1, PAR2 INTO tempTABLE 
  FROM originalTABLE
  WHERE ..CONDITIONS..
)
SELECT TOP 1 (tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2) AS FinalResult
FROM tempTable tbl1
INNER JOIN tempTable tbl2 on tbl2.PAR1 > tbl1.PAR1
INNER JOIN tempTable tbl3 on tbl3.PAR1 > tbl2.PAR1
ORDER BY tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
SELECT (tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2) AS FinalResult 
FROM (SELECT ID, PAR1, PAR2 FROM originalTABLE
WHERE ..CONDITIONS.
     ) AS tempTable tbl1 JOIN
     tempTable tbl2
     ON tbl2.PAR1 > tbl1.PAR1 JOIN
     tempTable tbl3 
     ON tbl3.PAR1 > tbl2.PAR1
ORDER BY tbl1.PAR2 + tbl2.PAR2 + tbl3.PAR2;
```

Only one set of parentheses is used for the subquery.

Note that you can also use:

```
ORDER BY FinalResult
```

Column aliases are recognized in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I already tried this one even before posting, but it gives me an error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @jeremy5 . . . Nothing in your question mentions views.  You cannot order in views.

Comment: I'm not using views in this case, but I had one ORDER after WHERE at the end of line: WHERE ..CONDITIONS... So I deleted that ORDER and put simple WHERE with one condition, but it  also gives me an error like "Incorrect syntax near 'tbl1'" in this line: ) AS tempTable tbl1 JOIN. Maybe something should be between tempTable and tbl1.